# What permissions are needed to run a system() command within a php script that writes to a folder?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, ffmpeg

I've got a php script which has the line:

```
system("ffmpeg -i ......");
```

The output folder is set to be:

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 apache apache   4096 Oct 19 07:40 in_upload
```

If I run the exact text "ffmpeg -i ......" from the prompt as root, it works fine.

But if the script is run, only a zero sized file is created. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

---

**Edit 1**

I think I've localized the problem to selinux

I tried the solution recommended in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#94929 :

```
<?php
function my_exec($cmd, $input='')
         {$proc=proc_open($cmd, array(0=>array('pipe', 'r'), 1=>array('pipe', 'w'), 2=>a$
          fwrite($pipes[0], $input);fclose($pipes[0]);
          $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);fclose($pipes[1]);
          $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);fclose($pipes[2]);
          $rtn=proc_close($proc);
          return array('stdout'=>$stdout,
                       'stderr'=>$stderr,
                       'return'=>$rtn
                      );
         }

echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('ls');
echo "\n2 ";
my_exec('ls');
echo "\n3 ";
my_exec('/bin/ls');

?>
```

Output was:

```
1 
2 
3
```

---

**Edit 2**

AFTER disabling selinux, I got the following results:

```
echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg');
echo "\n2 ";
echo system('ffmpeg');
echo "\n3 ";
echo exec('ffmpeg');
===> None worked

echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg');
echo "\n2 ";
echo system('/usr/bin/ffmpeg');
echo "\n3 ";
echo exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg');
===> None worked

echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('ls');
echo "\n2 ";
echo system('ls');
echo "\n3 ";
echo exec('ls');
===> All 3 worked as expected.
```

---

**Edit 3**

php script:

```
echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('touch test1.txt');
echo "\n2 ";
echo system('touch test2.txt');
echo "\n3 ";
echo exec('touch test3.txt');
```

error_log:

```
touch: cannot touch `test1.txt': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch `test2.txt': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch `test3.txt': Permission denied
```

php script:

```
echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('/bin/touch test1.txt');
echo "\n2 ";
echo system('/bin/touch test2.txt');
echo "\n3 ";
echo exec('/bin/touch test3.txt');
```

error_log:

```
/bin/touch: cannot touch `test1.txt': Permission denied
/bin/touch: cannot touch `test2.txt': Permission denied
/bin/touch: cannot touch `test3.txt': Permission denied
```

php script:

```
echo "1 ";
echo shell_exec('/bin/touch /var/www/html/beta/test1.txt');
echo "\n2 ";
echo system('/bin/touch /var/www/html/beta/test2.txt');
echo "\n3 ";
echo exec('/bin/touch /var/www/html/beta/test3.txt');
```

error_log:

```
/bin/touch: cannot touch `/var/www/html/beta/test1.txt': Permission denied
/bin/touch: cannot touch `/var/www/html/beta/test2.txt': Permission denied
/bin/touch: cannot touch `/var/www/html/beta/test3.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: What are the permissions on ffmpeg? Have you tried specifying the absolute path to ffmopeg instead of relying on detection at runtime? does your webserver run chroot?

Comment: ....and what happens when you try to run it using 'su apache -c ffmpeg -i ....'

Comment: Apparently I can't su into apache... I do have apache as a user though

Comment: Symcbean - are you able to su apache?

Comment: When you say "None worked", did you pass it actual arguments so as to see if it would convert?

Comment: Apologies - the query has "changed" somewhat from the original. I'm able to run only the ffmpeg program, but its output comes only in the error_log. If I pass parameters, it gives a permission denied error. So I am testing with touch as shown in Edit 3.

Comment: Does the user the web server is running as have permissions to write to that directory? Also, I don't get notification of responses unless you prefix the comment with "@Ignacio:".

Comment: @Ignacio - Sorry about that, didnt realize! About the permissions, the site and its files are all as root, but apache is the webserver. To what should i give permissions to apache? Just the key folder that the "script" is in, or the "destination" folder where the file should be created?

Comment: `/var/www/html/beta` should be writable by the web server user.

Comment: @Ignacio - changed it to the following, but it didnt help - drwxrwxr-x 19 apache apache     12288 Oct 25 08:20 beta

Answer (score 1):

A few random thoughts:

- How long does your ffpmpeg command takes ? if it takes longer than the value of max_execution_time in php.ini, I believe that the command is canceled.
- try to use only full paths for the ffmpeg binary and the input/output files. Although, if you have a zero size file outputted, it shouldn't be that.
- Does apache have the permission to run the ffmpeg binary ?
- try a basic command in your system call, such as "touch test.txt" just to check if the problem is from ffmpeg or your php script.

Comment: I dont think (1) is a problem. I've set the max_exec time to 5 mins. (2) ffmpeg is in the system path (3) I'm not sure! How do I test that? (4) you're right - this did NOT work - no file was created.

Comment: (1)is 5 minutes enough to encode your video ?. (3) what does "ps -edf|grep apache" returns ? the first column is the name of the user that runs apache, try to use it with "su <user> -c ffmpeg...". (4) this is a coding problem. can't help here.

Comment: ps -edf... returns: apache   19394  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19395  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19396  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19397  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19398  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19399  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19400  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   19401  9134  0 10:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     19960 16055  0 10:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep apache

Comment: I can't su apache... it says: This account is currently not available.

Comment: <?php

echo system("ls -al");

?>
 doesnt work either

Comment: Looks like 'apache' isnt allowed to do system() queries... how do i go about fixing that?

Comment: The system("ls..") command shows the following in error_log: "sh: ls: command not found"

Comment: Once again, try with the full path of the command. Probably /bin/ls. If it fails, then I believe you are running in a chroot and thus you must copy the relevant binary and linked libraries to your chroot before working with them.

Answer (score -1):

It was a permissions issue, I had selinux enabled. By changing the setting in /etc/sysconfig/selinux

```
From: 
SELINUX=enforcing

To:
SELINUX=disabled
```

The system() commands started working

Comment: Whoops! Spoke too soon... see edit2

Comment: under no circumstances should you ever make this a permanent fix.