# Cannot seem to disable SELINUX / phpinfo() shows: SELINUX_INIT YES

Tags: apache-2.2, php, selinux, phpinfo

Does this mean that selinux is currently enabled on my system?

In /etc/sysconfig/selinux, I set:

```
  SELINUX=disabled
```

AND then rebooted the server, but still in phpinfo() the same thing is showing up!

How do I disable it permanently?

(Nothing against selinux, but I have scripts that need to execute other programs - and it appears that selinux is interfering with them... [What permissions are needed to run a system() command within a php script that writes to a folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/192951/what-permissions-are-needed-to-run-a-system-command-within-a-php-script-that-wr))

Edit 1:

If it helps, I also did the same in: /etc/selinux/config

Comment: Where? None of my systems that run SELinux show this.

Comment: Interesting... it appears below the Environment block for me... and below PHP Variables it shows: _ENV["SELINUX_INIT"] YES

Comment: How can I check if its actually running?

Comment: This is something specific to your system/distro, and probably has nothing to do with whether or not SELinux is actually enabled.

Comment: The `sestatus` command will tell you.

Comment: Hmmm - okay... can you have a look at the linked question? I could use your insights into that issue!

Comment: Wokay - thanks ... root@server [~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That entry is an environment variable set by the system, and has nothing to do with whether or not SELinux is enabled. The way to check if SELinux is enabled is to run `sestatus`.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio - that command helped identify whether selinux was really active or not on my system!