# Cannot write log file 'ffmpeg2pass-0.log' for pass-1 encoding: Permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2, php, selinux, ffmpeg

Our PHP application is installed as 'root' on a Redhat5/CentOS system at: /var/www/html/beta/

After disabling SELINUX in order to allow these scripts to execute other programs on the system - [What permissions are needed to run a system() command within a php script that writes to a folder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/192951/what-permissions-are-needed-to-run-a-system-command-within-a-php-script-that-wr)

I faced the error that the Apache error_log showed this:

```
 Cannot write log file 'ffmpeg2pass-0.log' for pass-1 encoding: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had run ffmpeg as root at the same location, which created the 'ffmpeg2pass-0.log' log file.

I had changed permission on /var/www/html/beta to:

```
- drwxrwxr-x 19 apache apache 12288 Oct 25 08:20 beta
```

so that apache had appropriate permissions to write to the folder.

However, since I already had the log file at the same location (which had been created as 'root'), ***user 'apache' was unable to write/append to it!*** Hence the error message that I saw.

I simply deleted all instances of this file and that worked perfectly!